# How come jQuery doesn't always load?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my code, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        // Disable caching of AJAX responses */
        cache: false
    });

    //pop_i = setInterval( "load_result()", 1000 );
    load_result();
    load_f();
});
```

but it doesn't always load. I know this because `load_f()` has an alert which doesn't get triggered sometimes.

Comment: what do `load_result()` and `load_f()` do? maybe you're getting an error somewhere along the way before your alert is triggered...

Comment: what does load_result do ? have you run this using firebug? .. i'll wager you have a javascript error

Comment: I do have firebug and I don't see any JavaScript errors..

function load_result()
{
 $.getJSON( "http://somesite/loadresult.php", function(data) {
  if( data == undefined )
  {
   setTimeout( "load_result()", 2000 );
   return;
  }
  console.log( data );
  insert_result( data );
  setTimeout( "load_result()", 750 );
  
 } );
}

Comment: Put the code for both functions in your question so they'll get properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure your JavaScript looks right and you're not getting any errors in Firebug, chances are it's the JSON being sent back from the server that's tripping things up.

Where `load_f` fails to run copy-paste the result of your GET/POST requests from Firebug into your text-editor and pour through them with a fine-tooth comb to make sure the JSON is well-formed.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this applies to your situation.

I've just come across an issue whereby $(document).ready() event wasn't being fired.  As it turns out, the jQuery $(document).ready() event is not fired in async postbacks when used w/ ASP.net UpdatePanels.  One solution is to refactor the $(document).ready() logic into an explicit function () so that it can also be registered w/ the ASP.net Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager endRequest event (fired on every async postback).  Details can be found on the [question I posted earlier today...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971281/ie6-textbox-focus-causing-unexpected-call-to-method-or-property-access)

Comment: oops, just saw the **.php** in your comments above... guess my answer doesn't apply :(

Answer (score 1):

What happens in `load_result` and `load_f`? Since the `ready` function attaches a listener, if an error occurs you will sometimes not see it.